# ¿Cómo mantener el scroll del navegador en una sección determinada al recargar la página?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Buenas tardes mi duda es la siguiente, ¿como hago para mantener el scroll del navegador en una sección especifica, después de haber recargado la página mediante window.location.href?

Les explico un poco, relleno un formulario y en el último campo al pulsar enter envío una petición ajax y en el success recargo la página con un parámetro llamado nit, esto es para ver el carrito del cliente y que productos tiene cargados en la sesión.

```
  datos = $('#frmVenta').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: datos, nit,//acá están todos los parámetros (valores a enviar) del POST

    success: function(response){

       console.log("Respuesta del servidor:" + datos);
       window.location.href="p_ventas.php?nit="+nit; //ESTO RECARGA LA PAGINA Y CARGA LOS PRODUCTOS A SER COMPRADOS
       $("#search2").focus();   
       // $('#td-desc').val('#descripcion');

       }
   });
```

Lo que necesito es que al cargar la página, el navegador scrollee hacia #search2, cabe destacar que no puede pasarse #search2 mediante la url pues la query que muestra la precompra no muestra los productos nuevos y no tiene el efecto deseado, así que solo por Jquery.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!!

Comment: porque si haces un ajax recargas la pagina, podrías recargar con los datos retornados por el mismo ajax sin refrescar, y de esa manera poder utilizar una función que te lleve al div correspondiente, si quieres te doy un ejemplo de como mover el scroll a un elemento deseado.

Comment: Es que esa es la unica manera que encontré, pues hay una condición en el site que evalua al cargar si la variable de sesión $nit es diferente a vacía me muestre el carrito de productos asociados a ese nit, por eso lo trampeé de esa manera pues de las otras maneras no me funcionaba.

Comment: Si por favor muestrame el ejemplo amigo :D. Gracias por responder.

Comment: esta div "#search2" solo se muestra cuando se accede a la pagina con el parametro "nit"? que pasa si accedes sin ese parámetro?, no eixste o esta invisible?

Comment: #search2 siempre está presente puesto que es el campo de busqueda por código de barras, es decir ingresas un código de barras de un producto y si coincide trae los datos asociados a ese producto mediante ajax. Forma parte de un formulario.

Comment: La idea es que al ingresar un codigo de barras cargue la página y el screen esté posicionado en ese input para seguir ingresando productos, cuestión de UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me queda del todo claro lo que intentas hacer, es que la ventana scrollee hasta el input de id "search2"?

Si es así, acá te dejo un ejemplo con animacion usando la librería jquery

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  var parametro = $.urlParam('nit');
  if(parametro){
    $("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $('#search2').offset().top 
  }, 500);
  //$('#search2').focus();//Descomenta esto si ademas queres que se posicione el cursor automaticamente sobre el input.
  }
});

$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
```

```css
.relleno{
  background-color: red;
  height:1000px;
}

.relleno2{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="relleno"></div>
  <div class="relleno2">
    <input type="text" name="usrname" id="search2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Aca un ejemplo sin animacion:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  document.location.href="#search2";
  //$('#search2').focus();//Descomenta esto si ademas queres que se posicione el cursor automaticamente sobre el input.
});
```

```css
.relleno{
  background-color: red;
  height:1000px;
}

.relleno2{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="relleno"></div>
  <div class="relleno2">
    <input type="text" name="usrname" id="search2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo, me explico bien, el proceso es, que cuando $('#search2').keypress(function(e){}); el busca el producto en la base de datos mediante ajax y si lo consigue envía otro ajax con window.location.href="p_ventas.php?nit="+nit; es aquí después de que la página haya sido cargada que necesito el scroll. Lamento no explicarme bien.

Comment: Entiendo, el código que te pongo de ejemplo va en esa pagina, a la que llegas luego del segundo ajax, o a veces tenes que entrar a esta pagina y que no siempre te "scrolle" hacia #search2.

Comment: Sólo cuando existe el parametro nit en la url y esté cargado, es decir que se envíe el codigo de barras de #search2, el primer ajax registra la transacción y el segundo ajax recarga la página con el parametro nit

Comment: Tu código está bien, pero me descuadra el formulario que ya tengo armado debido al height jeje

Comment: Edite el primero de los ejemplos para que haga el scroll solo cuando encuentra un parametro "nit" en la url de la pagina, prueba y despues me dices, saludos, espero que te funcione.

Comment: Respuesta correcta, muchas gracias!!.

Answer (score 1):

Bien lo que se me ocurre para poder orientarte es que guardes en una cookie un flag para validar que necesites usar el scroolTo, de esta menera en el ready de tu pagina puedes ejecutar o no la acción de mover el scroll.

Para que el ejemplo que te paso funcione debes descomentar el uso de las cookies ya que en el simulador se bloquea por cuestiones de seguridad el uso de las mismas.

Espero que te oriente.

Saludos.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//Comento el uso de cookies ya que en este sandbox no esta permitido el uso //de las mismas, tu deberias usarla como el codigo comentado.
$(function(){
  //var isScroll = getCookie('isScroll');
  //if(isScroll == ""){
  //setCookie('isScroll', '0');
  //}
  $('#btnSimulator').click(function(){
      //setCookie('isScroll', '1');
      window.location.reload();
  });
  
/*Aqui es donde en primera instancia no va a accionar el scroll, al correr la callback del success del post vas a setear la cookie y cuando recarga hace el get y si correponde hace el scroll al elemento html con el id scrollHere*/

   
    var isScroll = '1';
  
  if(isScroll == '1'){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSimulator">Boton Simulador Success Ajax</button>

<ul>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li><li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
  <li> algo </li>
</ul>

<h3 id="scrollHere">Scroll aqui</h3>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo, me explico bien, el proceso es, que cuando $('#search2').keypress(function(e){}); el busca el producto en la base de datos mediante ajax y si lo consigue envía otro ajax con window.location.href="p_ventas.php?nit="+nit; es aquí después de que la página haya sido cargada que necesito el scroll. Lamento no explicarme bien.

Comment: Entonces quería pedirte que me explicaras para dummies de Jquery, Los cookies irían al inicio del script¿? que parte insertaría después del window.location.href¿?

Comment: Te doy positivo porque tu código cumple la funcionalidad, tengo que ver como lo adapto.

Comment: El uso de las cookies es una manera de persistir información entre paginas, en el código ejemplo están las dos funciones setCookye donde le pasas una key "nombreCookie" y un Valor, y el getCookie busca en el arreglo de cookies del document la que corresponda a la key pasada por parametro. por lo tanto al refrescar al inicio del ready validas si existe la cookie si es asi ingresa en la sección del ready que mueve el scroll, si no es así el scroll se queda quieto. cualquier duda dime e intento ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que me guarde el nit del usuario que es como la cedula o el rif, y me lo pase por url, si la url no está vacía que me haga scroll al search2 para seguir cargando productos :P

Comment: entonces puedes usar las funciones que se describen en el link que te voy a compartir para validar si en la url existe el parametro, y si la funcion es retorna null quiere decir que no existe por lo tanto no haces el scroll, mañana edito la respuesta para explicarte como seria: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo también seguiré intentando a ver que más se me ocurre, espero tu respuesta mañana!. Feliz día-

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por su pronta ayuda amigos, quisiera darles a todos mejor respuesta, pues todas las respuesta son validas, pero logré solventarlo con la respuesta de Leonardo.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var parametro = $.urlParam('nit');
 if(parametro){
 $("html, body").animate({ 
  scrollTop: $('#search2').offset().top 
 }, 500);
 //$('#search2').focus();//Descomenta esto si ademas queres que se posicione el cursor automaticamente sobre el input.
 }

});

$.urlParam = function(name){
   var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results==null){
   return null;
}
 else{
   return results[1] || 0;
 }
}
```

Lo que se hizo fue evaluar si existia el parametro nit en la url, para que sólo hiciera ese efecto si no estaba vacío y así se logra.

Geniales respuestas de ambos.

Comment: Genial, esa era la idea con la Url que te compartí ;) suerte y buenos códigos!